# AWS ssh connect show connection timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a new instance of Amazon EC2 in Amazon Web Services (AWS) by referring to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html). I even added a Security Group

Yesterday my instance is working fine.i setup every thing on my instance and my site is working fine
on this link 
http://34.207.113.186/

but today when i try to login via ssh it shows connection time out error

> ssh: connect to host ec2-xx-xx-xx-x.xxxxxxx-x.amazonaws.com port 22:
>   Invalid argument

i try to  restart my instance but same error is showing

how can i resolve this issue ?

Comment: When you stop and start your instance, the IP address and dns will change. Check if you are connecting to the correct dns name. I would suggest to connect with the public ip to see if it works.

Comment: Another reason would be in your security groups, you have only allowed port 22 for a specific address and your local machine's public ip might have changed. Try allowing port 22 for all IPs in the security group temporary to check if this is the issue.

Comment: @PubuduJayawardana yes i checked with new ip address and its working . thank you